# Regex pattern matching (Javascript/ASP)

Tags: regex

I need some help with a regular expression, please help if you can

I have the following code: I am using Javascript and ASP

> {In|inside|during|into|in the sphere
>   of} {this} {article|piece of
>   writing|editorial|commentary|paragraph|section}
>   {we} {will|desire to|wishto|want
>   to|resolve to|will} {tell} {you}
>   {more} {about|regarding|with reference
>   to} {the}

The desired code should look like this:

> {In|inside|during|into|in the sphere
>   of} this {article|piece of
>   writing|editorial|commentary|paragraph|section}
>   we {will|desire to|wishto|want
>   to|resolve to|will} tell you
>   more {about|regarding|with reference
>   to} the

The brackets around the single words with no | should be removed like - this - we - tell you more - the in the example above.

I am thinking that the solution should be something like this

```
replace(/{.+?[^\|]/ig, '');
```

to replace the { there should not be a | in the code; {.+?[^\|] and replace { with nothing

Then if there is not a starting { to replace the } with nothing

I am not sure how to do this, and how to only remove the {} where there is no | inside without removing the content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x.replace(/{([^|}]*)}/g, '$1')
```

Comment: Thanks Mark - works 100% I like your solution the best it leaves numbers in the text like {10|ten} 10 and ten...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var string = "{hello|there} {yes} {no|me} {ok}";
string = string.replace(/{[A-Za-z0-9]+)}/g, "$1");
```

Gives you:

```
{hello|there} yes {no|me} ok
```

Comment: what if there are numbers in the string?

Comment: Thanks vivin - Your sulution works, except fot the fact that if there is a number in the string I will loose it... but thanks a million appreciate the help!

Comment: @Gerald ah, since you said "words", I thought just "letters". :) I've edited the solution.